# Printing float number as integer in Python

Tags: python, int

So I want to print a float number as an integer. I have a float called "percentage" which should be like percentage=36.1 and I want to print it as an int number, with digits after comma missing.

I use the following code, which is more like using C logic:

```
percentage=36.1
print "The moisture  percentage is at %d %.", percentage
```

But that gives an error. How would I have to reform it so that it works in Python? What I want to print is:
"The moisture percentage is 36%."

Comment: `int(percentage)`

Answer (score 5):

```
percentage=36.1
print "The moisture  percentage is at %i%% " %percentage
```

Answer (score 5):

the [string format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) has a percentage already (where `1.0` is `100%`):

```
percentage = 36.1
print("The moisture  percentage is at {:.0%}".format(percentage/100))
```

where the `%` is the specifier for the percent format and the `.0` prevents any digits after the comma to be printed. the `%`-sign is added automatically.

usually the percentage is just a fraction (without the factor of 100). with `percentage = 0.361` in the first place there would be no need to divide by `100`.

---

starting from python >= 3.6 an f-string will also work:

```
percentage = 36.1
print(f"The moisture  percentage is at {percentage/100:.0%}")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see the different formatting options in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

```
print "The moisture  percentage is at {0:.0f} %.".format(percentage)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
percentage=36.1
print "The moisture  percentage is at %d %s"%(percentage,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

In `python3.x`

```
percentage=36.1
print("The moisture percentage is at "+str(int(percentage))+"%")
```